# XML false vs (string) false

Tags: xml

How can I represent, true/false as the Boolean and "true"/"false" the strings in XML?

Eg.

```
<problem>false</problem>
<problem>problem_name</problem>
```

Or is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

According to the spec, you can use the literal values true, false, 1, 0 but you should use true or false only.

Chris

*"3.2.2 boolean*

[Definition:]  boolean has the ·value space· required to support the mathematical concept of binary-valued logic: {true, false}.
3.2.2.1 Lexical representation

An instance of a datatype that is defined as ·boolean· can have the following legal literals {true, false, 1, 0}.
3.2.2.2 Canonical representation

The canonical representation for boolean is the set of literals {true, false}."

Comment: One isn't required to use `xs:boolean` for boolean values, however. While there are certainly good reasons for this, there's precedent for doing it differently - e.g. XSLT uses `yes` and `no` consistently, and a corresponding enumeration can be defined in the schema.

Answer (score 1):

It is a common unwritten rule that says in xml as a boolean value we should use: 'true' and 'false'

You can look here for further information:
http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#boolean

Answer (score 1):

You want to distinguish between "real" booleans and the texts "true" and "false"?

Well - an attribute might help you - e.g. *IsActive*.
For "text":

```
<problem>false</problem>
```

For booleans:

```
<problem IsActive="false"></problem>
```

Comment: I cannot accept that a string value is the better solution for store a boolean flag. The most important thing is the possible values. In this case can write any string to attribute :(

Answer (score 1):

If you use a schema to define an element's type as string, anything using that schema to interpret the element's content will correctly interpret `false` as being a string.

If you're not using a schema, and processes have to guess at a piece of content's type based on its representation, then you're going to have problems.  You have to provide processes with some way of disambiguation, e.g. an attribute that indicates the content's data type, or (shudder) enclosing ambiguous literal values in quotation marks, i.e. `"false"` for the string and `false` for the boolean.  Any approach you take here will be non-standard and non-portable.

Comment: I wouldn't know where to start.  Look at how data types are implemented in .NET's XML representation of the ADO.NET data set for a pretty fully-functional real-world example.